# remove attribute disable for all elements excepting some classes

Tags: jquery, readonly, apply

I have this in order to replace attribute disabled with readonly and I want to know if it is possible to not do that for some classes. I want to add something like "if the input does not have class x do action"

```
$('input[type=text][disabled="disabled"]').removeAttr("disabled").attr("readonly", true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to exclude elements from the matched set:

```
$('input[type=text][disabled="disabled"]').not(".someClass").removeAttr("disabled").attr("readonly", true);
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-selector, but as the documentation states, the `.not` method is better "in most cases".

As a side note, you should probably be using the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method rather than `attr`, since both `disabled` and `readonly` are DOM properties.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not(.x)` pseudo selector.

```
$('input[type=text][disabled="disabled"]:not(.x)')
.removeAttr("disabled").attr("readonly", true);
```

You can simplify it like this.

```
$('input:text:disabled:not(.x)')
.removeAttr("disabled").attr("readonly", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using not() and prop() should do it;

```
$('input[type="text"]:disabled').not('.className')
    .prop('disabled', false).prop('readonly', true);
```

See the [disabled selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/), [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text][disabled="disabled"][class!="yourClass"]').removeAttr("disabled").attr("readonly", true);
```

Should also work